# How to replace sub queries with joint queries?

Tags: mysql, join

Given below is a working query. I would like to replace all subqueries with direct joint query. Kindly suggest me a solution.

```
SELECT
  id,
  startTime,
  endTime,
  drawingTime,
  result,
  wpAmount,
  lpAmount,
  prize,
  cntWinTickets,
  cntLoosTickets
FROM (SELECT
    i.id            AS id,
    i.start_time    AS startTime,
    i.end_time      AS endTime,
    i.drawing_time  AS drawingTime,
    i.result        AS result,
    SUM( t.amount ) AS wpAmount,
    SUM( t.prize )  AS prize,
    COUNT( t.id )   AS cntWinTickets
      FROM issues i
    LEFT JOIN orders o
      ON o.issue_id = i.id
    LEFT JOIN tickets t
      ON t.order_id = o.id
        AND t.has_prize = 1
      GROUP BY i.id) AS A
  INNER JOIN (SELECT
        i.id            AS lid,
        SUM( t.amount ) AS lpAmount,
        COUNT( t.id )   AS cntLoosTickets
          FROM issues i
        LEFT JOIN orders o
          ON o.issue_id = i.id
        LEFT JOIN tickets t
          ON (t.order_id = o.id
              AND (t.has_prize = 0
                OR t.has_prize IS NULL))
          GROUP BY i.id) AS B
    ON A.id = B.lid
```

Comment: maybe its best if you create a **VIEW**

Comment: can you post schema and desired output. along with some sample data it would be better to solve

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, with a fancy cross product in the SUM operator. I think it would be better not to do this but it's fun!

```
SELECT i.id AS id,
       i.start_time AS startTime,
       i.end_time AS endTime,
       i.drawing_time AS drawingTime,
       i.result AS result,
       SUM( t.amount*COALESCE(t.has_prize,0) ) AS wpAmount,
       SUM( t.prize*COALESCE(t.has_prize,0) ) AS prize,
       COUNT( case when t.has_prize=1 then t.id end ) AS cntWinTickets,
       SUM( t.amount*(1-COALESCE(t.has_prize,0)) ) AS lpAmount,
       COUNT( case when COALESCE(t.has_prize,0)=0 then t.id end ) AS cntLoosTickets
FROM issues i
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.issue_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN tickets t ON t.order_id = o.id AND t.has_prize in (null,0,1)
GROUP BY i.id
```

Comment: what is this? why multiple here `t.amount*COALESCE(t.has_prize,0)`

Comment: `t.has_prize` is either `1`, `0` or `NULL`. If you want to sum when `t.has_prize` is equal to `1`, the you can do a cross product. And the contrary applys for `t.amount*(1-COALESCE(t.has_prize,0))`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT i.id AS id, 
       i.start_time AS startTime, 
       i.end_time AS endTime, 
       i.drawing_time AS drawingTime, 
       i.result, 
       SUM(case when t.has_prize=1 then t.amount end) AS wpAmount, 
       SUM(case when t.has_prize=1 then t.prize end) AS prize, 
       COUNT(case when t.has_prize=1 then t.id end) AS cntWinTickets,
       SUM(case when coalesce(t.has_prize,0)=0 then t.amount end) AS lpAmount, 
       COUNT(case when coalesce(t.has_prize,0)=0 then t.id end) AS cntLoosTickets
FROM issues i
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.issue_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN tickets t ON t.order_id = o.id AND t.has_prize in (null,0,1)
GROUP BY i.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can combine it

```
SELECT
  i.id           AS id,
  i.start_time   AS startTime,
  i.end_time     AS endTime,
  i.drawing_time AS drawingTime,
  i.result       AS result,
  SUM(IF t.has_prize = 1,t.amount,0) AS wpAmount,
  SUM(IF t.has_prize = 1,t.prize,0) AS prize,
  COUNT(IF t.has_prize = 1,t.id,0) AS cntWinTickets,
  SUM(IF t.has_prize = 0,t.amount,0) AS lpAmount,
  COUNT(IF t.has_prize = 0,1,0) AS cntLoosTickets
FROM issues i
  LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.issue_id = i.id
  LEFT JOIN tickets t ON t.order_id = o.id
GROUP BY i.id
```

`IF t.has_prize = 1,t.amount,0` it means if `t.has_prize = 1` than take `t.amount` else take `0`. Alternate is CASE which Mark has used.